# Do demons get any special honorifics?

Tags: honorifics

Do demons get any special honorifics put after their names?

I'm wanting to say to a Finnish person studying English and Japanese

> If [Lordi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lordi)-(honorific for demon) can manage English, I think you can
>   too!

I don't know whether demons get their own honorific, but the fact that demons have a different [counter word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Common_counters_by_category) to humans makes me wonder whether they have their own honorific.

Comment: I don't think so, but there's an entertainer who goes by the name [デーモン閣下](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Kakka) :-)

Comment: demonsは「一人、二人」でなく「一匹、二匹」ですか？

Comment: @Chocolate the Japanese edition of Wikipedia also claims that demons get "匹": [link](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E6%95%B0%E8%A9%9E#.E4.B8.80.E8.A6.A7) "鬼 - 一匹・疋（ひき）". Are you sure?

Comment: The problem is that 鬼 is only part of demons.  Western-type demons are usually called not 鬼 but 悪魔, and they may be counted as 人 (depending on their appearance?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no particular honorific which is used for demons but not for humans. But it would be possible to add "sama" on to the name of a particularly powerful demon, in the same way as "hotoke sama" (仏様) or "kami sama" (神様). However, it is my firm opinion that "san" or "shi" (氏) would not be used for a "demon".

Comment: As I suggested in a comment on the question, “demon” can mean both 鬼 and 悪魔, and 鬼 is usually counted as 一匹, 二匹 just like animals, not as 一人, 二人.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Thank you for your comments and attempts to answer this. I don't really understand the question very well but attempted to give an answer to the best of my abilities.